# Reference for the sensitivity of consumers to firms' credit policy between developed and developing countries?

Tags: reference-request, nonexpert

I am finding references for the one of these three ideas here:

1. Consumers in developing countries are more sensitive to credit policy of firms in developed countries. Or how prudent or relax that firms in developing follow to compete compared to firms in developed countries.

Or

2. A reference says that firms in developing countries trust the consumers more than firms in developed countries.

Or

3. Reference for the idea that Firms in developing are more likely to relax their credit policy to compete than firms in developed market.

I am wondering if you can also suggest to me which keyword I should try to search for the references relevant as well.

Thanks in advance.
Update:
I just found a paper mentioning that firms in developing countries where formal lenders are scarce at best, trade credit plays an even more significant role in funding firms' activities [(Fisman, 2001)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305750X00000966) but it is not what I am looking for.